# Wordpress hook for <!--more--> tag

Tags: wordpress, hook

I want to insert a video right before where the `<!--more-->` tag has been placed on single post page, and the posts index.

Is there a hook to add code before or after the author's `<!--more-->` tag in a post?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a filter:

```
function more_filter($content) {
    return str_replace('<!--more-->', 'video code <!--more-->', $content);

}
add_filter('the_content', 'more_filter', 1, 1);
```

Adjust the priority so the filter runs before the `<!--more-->` tag is removed.